# Dojo: adding static data to filteringSelect

Tags: dojo, widget

How can I add some static data to filteringSelect, in addition to existing store that loads data via ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find descent solution. Anyway, I don't think that the very idea is good. Either get all data from server dynamically or keep everything on client side.